# Create custom aggregation function with ordered factor column in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm not sure if aggregation is the right approach here, but it's my best guess. My data has duplicates with different grades, ex. A vs A+. There may also be different states, but that doesn't matter.

```sql
CREATE TABLE example_table
(
    id varchar(255),
    state varchar(255),
    grade varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO example_table (id, state, grade)
VALUES (31, 'CO', 'A'), (31, 'CO', 'A+'), (52, 'CA', 'A'), (52, 'CO', 'A+');
```

What I want to return is the tuple with the highest grade only for each id. (31, 'CO', 'A+'), (52, 'CO', 'A+')

I also need to define the grade structure, which is (from best to worst): P, A+, A, B, C, D, F.

I'm working in Snowflake but I'm hoping the solution would be software-agnostic.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses a case expression and `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select et.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by case grade when 'P' then 1 when 'A+' then 2 when 'A' then 3 when 'B' then 4 when 'C' then 5 when 'D' then 6 when 'F' then 7 else 8 end
                               ) as seqnum
      from example_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can simplify this by noting that except for `'P'` and `'A+'` the rest are in alphabetical order:

```
select t.*
from (select et.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by case grade when 'P'  then 1 when 'A+' then 2 else 3 end,
                                         grade
                               ) as seqnum
      from example_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or use a derived table for an explicit lookup:

```
select t.*
from (select et.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by v.grade nulls last
                               ) as seqnum
      from example_table t left join
           (values ('P', 1), ('A+', 2), ('A', 3), . . .
           ) v(grade, ord)
           on t.grade = v.grade
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I actually prefer this method (or having an explicit reference table for grades) because it seems the least prone to error.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Linoff. For some reason, the derived table did not work but the CASE WHEN statement did.

Comment: @BlakeShurtz . . . The exact syntax for the second solution depends on the database you are using.